# Why does a trailing template literal execute a function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Came across this javascript riddle on Twitter today: https://twitter.com/bradleymeck/status/890795540123865088

``` // #js
const a = f => f``;
const b = f => f``;
console.log(a(_ => _) === b(_ => _));
// what do you think this will/may print ```

At first glance it actually seems to make some decent sense. `a` is a function that takes some input `f` and then does ``` f`` ```. What ``` f`` ``` is a complete mystery to me so I tossed it into the console and received this input.

``` (()=>{console.log('hi')})`` ```

> hi

So it seems that a trailing template literal executes its preceding function. I understand that template literals are code that is executed immediately, but this behavior makes no sense to me. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: It's a tagged template literal: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals_and_escape_sequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this piece of code can help you:

```
var test1 = 2;
var test2 = 3;

function fTest(strings, ...params){
  strings.forEach((x) => console.log(`string param: ${x}`));
    params.forEach((x, index) => console.log(`param ${index}: ${x}`));
}

const a = (f, param1, param2) => f`tagged ${param1} template ${param2} literals`;
a(fTest, test1, test2);
```

That mistery is a **tagged template literal**:
essentially you're passing a template literals to your function, which will interpret the place holders as parameters, as well as the strings between them.

You can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) the documentation.

Another thing: if you want to ignore escape sequences you can use the `raw` function on the `strings` (see the example).